# Importing a css file for a different page in React

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I am having an issue where when I try and import css onto each page, it will appear on all pages instead of just one. I have my CSS importing in _document.js

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html>
      <Head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha512-xX2rYBFJSj86W54Fyv1de80DWBq7zYLn2z0I9bIhQG+rxIF6XVJUpdGnsNHWRa6AvP89vtFupEPDP8eZAtu9qA==" crossOrigin="anonymous" referrerPolicy="no-referrer" />
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

and I want to know how I can import this CSS on a per-page basis, instead of having all css files on all pages. I have tried importing the css inside of each JS file, but it seems to want to go to `/pagehere/styles/settings.css` instead of `/styles/settings.css` even when I put `import '../styles/settings.css'`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<Link>`s and try using `import '../../stryles/settings.css'` instead.

Comment: That's not the issue though, the links work fine however it doesn't work on a per page basis, it just imports them all onto every page.